# How to put iText LIST on absolute position with certain font and alignment?

Tags: java, itext

```
public void printTextOnAbsolutePosition(String teks, PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rectangle, boolean useAscender) throws Exception {
    Font fontParagraf = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL);
    rectangle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
    rectangle.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
    rectangle.setBorderWidth(0.0f);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    cb.rectangle(rectangle);

    Paragraph para = new Paragraph(teks, fontParagraf);
    ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(cb);
    columnText.setSimpleColumn(rectangle);
    columnText.setUseAscender(useAscender);
    columnText.addText(para);

    columnText.setAlignment(3);
    columnText.setLeading(10);
    columnText.go();
}
```

We can use the above code to print text with iText on absolute position. But how can we achieve the same with List? Also, how to format the text of the list so it uses certain font and text alignment?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void putBulletOnAbsolutePosition(String yourText, PdfWriter writer, Float koorX, Float koorY, Float lebarX, Float lebarY) throws Exception {
    List listToBeShown = createListWithBulletImageAndFormatedFont(yourText);

    // ... (the same) ...

    columnText.addElement(listToBeShown);
    columnText.go();
}
```

The method is essentially the same. By looking at the documentation, we find that instead of using `.addtext` on ColumnText, we use `.addElement` which accept  Paragraph, List, PdfPTable and Image.

As for formating the list text, we simply need to make paragraf as the input for the list (and not using `columnText.setAlignment()` to set the alignment).

```
public List createListWithBulletImageAndFormatedFont(String yourText) throws Exception {
    Image bulletImage = Image.getInstance("src/main/resources/japoimages/bullet_blue_japo.gif");
    bulletImage.scaleAbsolute(10, 8);
    bulletImage.setScaleToFitHeight(false);

    List myList = new List();
    myList.setListSymbol(new Chunk(Image.getInstance(bulletImage), 0, 0));

    String[] yourListContent = yourText.split("__");
    Font fontList = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL);

    for (int i=0; i < yourListContent.length; i++) {
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(yourListContent[i], fontList);
        para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        myList.add(new ListItem(para));
    }
    return myList;
}
```

The above codes will print bulleted list (using image) on any location we desire.

```
public void putBulletnAbsolutePosition (String dest) throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5, 30,30, 60, 40);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();

    String myText = "ONE__TWO__THREE__FOUR";
    putBulletOnAbsolutePosition(myText, writer, 140f, 350f, 300f, 200f);

    document.close();
}
```